# QProcess call gksudo with parameter for individualized message for calling script

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, gksudo

How can I parse a parameter like **--message "text"** to **/usr/bin/gksudo** using **QProcess** to show my individualized text?

Just with */usr/bin/gksudo* and calling my *script.sh* it works fine.

Here the minimal example:

```
QString cmd = QString("/usr/bin/gksudo");
QStringList param = ( QStringList << "--message my Text" << "path/to/script.sh")

QProcess.start( cmd, param );
```

Even if i try to add the parameter to the *cmd* i fail. And no password prompt is shown.

```
QString cmd = QString("/usr/bin/gksudo --message MyText");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QProcess takes the first parameter as the command to run and then passes the following arguments, delimited by a space, as arguments to the command.

When you do this: -

```
QStringList param = ( QStringList << "--message my Text" << "path/to/script.sh")
```

And then pass param to QProcess, it's passing "path/to/script.sh" as a command line parameter to gksudo, but what you want is a single argument with **--message**. You need to unify the parameters with extra quotes. So, in the case of your last example, that would be: -

QString cmd = QString("/usr/bin/gksudo \"--message MyText"\");

Note the two additional **\"** around **--message MyText**

Passing this to QProcess means there are two arguments; the call to **gksudo** and its command line argument "**--message MyText**"

Comment: I’d try with `”—message” << “my text” << “/path/to/script.sh”` first

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, that would produce the same problem. If using a QStringList, you still need a single argument to gksudo, so it would need to be << "-message -text \"/path/to/script.sh\"" as "my text" and "/path/to/script.sh" are not valid arguments to pass to gksudo on their own.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

**--message** and **my Text** are both own elements.

```
QStringList param = ( QStringList << "--message" << tr("my Text") << "path/to/script.sh")
```